# inflate popup menu items programmatically

Tags: android

I have a button in my activity, pressing upon which, the following method gets called -

```
private ArrayList<ListView> myListViewList;
private ArrayList<MyListAdapter> myAdapterList;

public void onPopupButtonClick(View button) {
    Log.v(TAG, "onPopupButtonClick");

    PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, button);
    Menu menu = popup.getMenu();

    // how do I display the myListViewList as items of in this popup menu
    // i.e how do I inflate myListViewList into menu object?
}
```

I know how to do this programmatically for an activity - creating linearlayouts and listViews and finally using addContentView on the activity's context.

But finding it hard to do the same for the popup menu scenario as described above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this code for Pop-up window

```
 LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) PopupMain.this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
 final View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup,        
 (ViewGroup)findViewById(R.id.popup_menu_root));
 PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(layout, 300,100, true);
 pw.dismiss();
 pw.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 10);
```

And your New pop-up layout should be as follows :

Popup.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/popup_menu_root"
   android:background="#FFFFFF"
   android:orientation="vertical"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="20dip" >
  <TextView android:id="@+id/popup_menu_button1"
     android:text="Copy"
     android:textColor="#000000"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

This line decide the Height and width of your New View(Pop up window)

```
  PopupWindow pw = new PopupWindow(layout, 300,100, true);
```

and `pw.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.BOTTOM, 0, 10);`

tells where the Pop-up window should displays..

Comment: Hi, The code snippet you gave me tells me how to create a PopupWindow instance. But my question is, how do i inflate a listView into the resulting PopupWindow View? Or is it even possible? Should i be looking at Dialogs instead to achieve my goal? My goal is to display a listView (or an ArrayList of ListViews) when the popup menu button is clicked. Thanks.

Comment: Yep. Is that even possible? Also, i would like to inflate the ListView programatically since i might have to display more than one ListView contents inside the popup view (something that will be determined during run time).

Comment: After some experimentation, i found that it is possible to add a listView (or even an array of listviews) to the popupWindow view. the only problem is that none of the elements is focussable. But interestingly, they are clickable. I have to find out why the individual items in the list are not focussable even though i am setting it to be explicitly in the list's custom adapter.

Comment: get error The method findViewById(int) is undefined for the type new View.OnClickListener(){} . Im inflating this in non activity class